# Express server serving index.html instead of chunk files, in a React app

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to serve a production build of a React app(Typescript), booted with create-react-app.

I'm following the official guide: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/

There's nothing unique about my setup. This is the server.js file, located in the root directory(above src):

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));


app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
 app.listen(8000);
```

The production files are created within a folder called build. An example of the paths generated:

```
  <script src="./static/js/main.0ae46692.chunk.js"></script>
```

When i navigate to localhost:8000/, everything is served fine. The initial request serves the index.html, and the script requests serve the correct files.

But, when i try to navigate(from the browser) to something like localhost:8000/todos, all script requests return index.html.

I do not see anything "special" about my setup, and do not understand what's going on. Am i missing something in the guide? It clearly states that `app.get('/*',...)` fixes the issue.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like the issue is the script tags are generated with [relative paths](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths), because it works when you make a request to the root /, but not anything else. Could you try setting the "homepage" to "http://localhost:8000"?

Comment: Hmm that did the trick. Also, when i did homepage:"/", it works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying the comment into an answer here so it can be marked.

This sounds like the issue is the script tags are generated with [relative paths](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths), because it works when you make a request to the root /, but not anything else. Could you try setting the "homepage" to "localhost:8000"